# What does negative values for Grid Layout Indicate

Tags: layout, awt, grid-layout

I came accross this code where Grid constraints are having negative row and column values. What does it signify?

```
GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
cons.gridx = 0;
cons.gridy = -2;
cons.gridwidth = 0;
cons.gridheight = 1;
cons.anchor = 10;
cons.fill = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative values for `gridx` and `gridy` indicate relative positioning, i.e. the component is placed just to the right of the component added before (for `gridx`) or just below the component (for `gridy`).

You should not use negative values directly but `GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE` instead.